# Why does my hero image disappear when I'm on mobile view on physical device but shows up fine in Chrome dev tool simulator devices?

Tags: html, css, debugging

I'm trying to figure out why my hero image disappears when I'm on a physical device in portrait mode.  The strange part's that it shows up perfectly fine and responsive when I'm using chrome's dev tool's device simulators.

If I remove `height: auto;` from `.image-wrapper img`, then my hero image appears on my physical device in mobile view but it won't be responsive across all devices.  I really need that `height: auto;` for it to be responsive across all devices.

What can I do to solve this?

**CSS and HTML**:

```css
@media (max-width: 600px) {
.image-wrapper {
    background-image: url("https://mario.nintendo.com/static/70f0ba342c3bb756ced4ba67505a1e08/d31fb/character.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -ms-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

.image-wrapper img {
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    height: auto;
 }
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
   <div class="image-wrapper">
       <img width="375" height="570"/>
   </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no sense in adding @media screen for devices under 600px since the images width is smaller than 600px

all you need is to add the image source in the html code and you don't need any css styling for this

```
<a href="#">
   <div class="image-wrapper">
       <img src="https://mario.nintendo.com/static/70f0ba342c3bb756ced4ba67505a1e08/d31fb/character.png" width="375" height="570"/>
   </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you add the image as a background only if the width is 600px or less in your CSS if the width is more than that there is no image because of your CSS :))))

you can add the image as `<img src="your img url" />` or you can specify the background image outside of media

Comment: But the width of my iPhone 7 is 375px so it should show up on my physical device.  Not sure how it's showing up on Chrome's dev tool device simulators :(

Answer (score 0):

Does it answer your question?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
        }

        .container {
            width: 100vw;
            height: 100vh;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            flex-direction: row;
        }

        @media (max-width: 600px) {
            .container img{
                width: 300px;
                height: 500px;
            }
        }
        
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box">
            <img src="https://mario.nintendo.com/static/70f0ba342c3bb756ced4ba67505a1e08/d31fb/character.png" width="375" height="570" alt="Character Image">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```